# How to upload my Google Gadget into my domain

Tags: google-gadget

May I know how to insert a Google Gadget into my domain (mydomain.com)? I searched around the web, but I still don't find a way to do this. Please help. Thanks.

[image]

I see this one - http://code.google.com/p/google-feedserver/wiki/PrivateGadgetAdministratorsGuide, but I am not sure this is the right one to do?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer =>

**Upload private gadget with this way:**
http://google-feedserver.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/resources/gadgets/private-gadget-editor/spec.xml

**Publish private gadget with this way:**
http://google-feedserver.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/resources/gadgets/domain-gadget-directory-manager/spec.xml